# rabbitmq dead letter queue is deleted

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm successfully established Rabbitmq 3.3.1 queues in the application including DLX usage. Requirement is to read DLQ messages, update them and resend to the original queue. I use QueueingConsumer, channel.basicConsume and consumer.nextDelivery to read specified number of messages. But - after read is successfully finished, the queue is disappear, even there are more messages in the queue...
The DLX declaration is:

> channel.exchangeDeclare(dlxName, FANOUT, true, false, true, args);
>     channel.queueDeclare(dlqName, true, false, true, args);

What can be wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third boolean argument to queueDeclare is `true`, that argument stands for `auto delete`, so when you close your AMQP connection, the queue is deleted.

Comment: In addition, QueueingConsumer is deprecated... After changing the code all is OK